# Enumerating large Azure BLOB containers using Azure.Storage.Blobs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

With `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob` one could enumerate a large BLOB container using the `BlobContinuationToken` in the `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` method, and the `BlobResultSegment` would include the `ContinuationToken` property if a subsequent read would be required to retrieve more from the container.

With `Azure.Storage.Blobs` it appears the enumeration API is `BlobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync` but the method signature does not provide a means of supplying a continuation token, and the results as `Azure.AsyncPageable<BlobItem>` do not appear to provide a property that is a continuation token.

Does anyone have a code snippet for enumerating large BLOB containers on Azure, using continuation tokens, via the `Azure.Storage.Blobs` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use a continuation token you can do so:

```cs
    string continuationToken = null;
    var container = new BlobContainerClient("xxx", "test");
    var blobPages = container.GetBlobsAsync().AsPages();
        
    await foreach (var page in blobPages)
    {
        continuationToken = page.ContinuationToken;
        foreach(var blob in page.Values)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

You can pass the token to `AsPages` to continue iteration:

```cs
blobPages = container.GetBlobsAsync().AsPages(continuationToken: continuationToken);
```

or you can just iterate over the blobs, let the SDK do the job of providing all the data using a stream of blobs:

```cs
    var container = new BlobContainerClient("xxx", "test");
    var blobs = container.GetBlobsAsync();
        
    await foreach (var blob in blobs)
    {
        //
    }
```

Iterating over the blobs can make multiple calls to the blob service.

For more about pagination in the SDK see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/pagination).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed.  Yes, I agree the best approach would be to allow the SDK to do its job, but in this case, the implementation expects a continuation token.  Thanks for putting this answer together Peter!